# Multiprocess insert in sqlite3 takes more time than serial python 3

Tags: python, sqlite, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

What I'm trying to achieve is extract files' metadata given a specific directory and store it in a .db file with python's sqlite3. I used python's multiprocessing to gain advantage of the parallel computation of some hash values for each file (use one core for each file at a time), although the serial code always achieves less computation time that the parallel one. I tested this in many machines with 2-8gb ram and 2-4 cores, collecting data from many files (some of them with size bigger than 1gb), always the same result. Below I present you the serial and the parallel python script, any idea would be really helpful.

The multiprocessing script:

```
import itertools
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os, sys
import stat
import sqlite3
import time
import hashlib


def worker(filename):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('metadata.db', timeout=30.0)
    c = conn.cursor()   #database cursor
    result = os.stat(filename)  #stat instance to get info about the current file

    print("Gathering metadata for file: " + filename)
    split_filename = filename.split('/')
    path_to_file = '/'.join(split_filename[:-1])
    file_name = split_filename[len(split_filename) - 1]

    #just things to get info about file
    if '.' in file_name:
        file_type = file_name.split('.', 1)
        name = file_type[0]
        file_type = file_type[1]
    else:
        file_type = 'null'
        name = file_name

    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(path_to_file + '/' + file_name, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)

    md5 = hash_md5.hexdigest()

    hash_sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
    with open(path_to_file + '/' + file_name, 'rb') as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b''):
            hash_sha256.update(chunk)

    sha256 = hash_sha256.hexdigest()


    print('Current process: ' + str(multiprocessing.current_process()))
    #insert into database
    try:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO metadata VALUES (null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (name, file_name, result.st_mode, result.st_size,
         result.st_atime, result.st_mtime, result.st_ctime, path_to_file, file_type, md5, sha256))
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print('!!Error Aqlite3: ' + e)

    conn.commit()


def main():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('metadata.db', timeout=30.0)
    c = conn.cursor()

    #check if table exists otherwise create one
    tb_exists = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='metadata'"
    if not conn.execute(tb_exists).fetchone():
        c.execute('''CREATE TABLE metadata
                        (unique_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name text, full_name text, mode text, size real,
                         atime real, mtime real, ctime real, location text, type text, md5 text, sha256 text)''')

    conn.close()    
    print('Number of CPUs: ' + str(multiprocessing.cpu_count()))
    pool = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) # pool of cpu_count processes

    walk = os.walk("/directoy/you/want/to/make/extraction")
    fn_gen = itertools.chain.from_iterable((os.path.join(root, file)
                                            for file in files)
                                           for root, dirs, files in walk)

    t1 = time.time()
    results_of_work = pool.map(worker, fn_gen) # this does the parallel processing
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('Entire Computation took: ' + str(time.time() - t1) + ' seconds')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The serial script:

```
import itertools
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os, sys
import stat
import sqlite3
import time
import hashlib


def worker(file_list, conn):
    c = conn.cursor()   #database cursor

    for file_name in file_list:
        result = os.stat(file_name) #stat instance to get info about the current file

        print("Gathering metadata for file: " + file_name)
        split_filename = file_name.split('/')
        path_to_file = '/'.join(split_filename[:-1])
        file_name = split_filename[len(split_filename) - 1]

        #just things to get info about file
        if '.' in file_name:
            file_type = file_name.split('.', 1)
            name = file_type[0]
            file_type = file_type[1]
        else:
            file_type = 'null'
            name = file_name

        hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
        with open(path_to_file + '/' + file_name, "rb") as f:
            for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
                hash_md5.update(chunk)

        md5 = hash_md5.hexdigest()

        hash_sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
        with open(path_to_file + '/' + file_name, 'rb') as f:
            for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b''):
                hash_sha256.update(chunk)

        sha256 = hash_sha256.hexdigest()

        #insert into database
        try:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO metadata VALUES (null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (name, file_name, result.st_mode, result.st_size,
             result.st_atime, result.st_mtime, result.st_ctime, path_to_file, file_type, md5, sha256))
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print('!!Error Aqlite3: ' + e)

        conn.commit()


def main():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('metadata_serial.db', timeout=30.0)
    c = conn.cursor()

    #check if table exists otherwise create one
    tb_exists = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='metadata'"
    if not conn.execute(tb_exists).fetchone():
        c.execute('''CREATE TABLE metadata
                        (unique_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name text, full_name text, mode text, size real,
                         atime real, mtime real, ctime real, location text, type text, md5 text, sha256 text)''')


    walk = os.walk("/directoy/you/want/to/make/extraction")
    fn_gen = itertools.chain.from_iterable((os.path.join(root, file)
                                            for file in files)
                                           for root, dirs, files in walk)
    file_list = list(fn_gen)
    t1 = time.time()

    worker(file_list, conn)

    print('Entire Computation took: ' + str(time.time() - t1) + ' seconds')
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the root cause is that sqlite3 does not work well with multiprocessing:

> SQLite itself does not welcome high-concurrency transactions as it will **lock the file during writing**. To work around this limitation, a queueing system should be in place. ...

Source: [How to do multiprocessing/multi-threading in Python with SQLite](https://atomh.wordpress.com/2017/01/02/how-to-do-multiprocessingmulti-threading-in-python-with-sqlite/)

Comment: That means that the serialization occurs in sqlite3 locks. Shouldn't the 'parallelization' of hash computations overlap that overhead? As you can see each process computes the hash values before trying to insert in the database.

Comment: @MariosKaratisoglou You might want to profile your two `worker` methods to clearly see where the slow part is. I noticed that in your multiprocessing `worker` it connects to db for each file it processes, which might introduce lots of overheads.